# Launch option -novid not working for Dota2

Tags: dota-2

The title does explain my question quite well, but here is some more details about the option itself. The -novid launch option for Dota2 can be set through the Steam Library page. It disables Valve's intro (The guy with the valve at the back of his head) before starting dota.

Here is a picture of my launch options:

[image: Screenshot of launch options]

Comment: Show us a screenshot of your launch parameters please. I have a hunch.

Comment: Sure, here is a image http://puu.sh/bOhz1/20862e7c8f.png although you can't see all the parameters you can see the -novid. Here is the full thing: (-console-novid-noaafonts-high-noforcemaccel -noforcemspd -useforcedmparms) And thank you for responding!

Comment: My hunch was right :P

Comment: After I finish downloading an update, will check to see if it worked. If it does, good sir. You will earn a completed question (if that is how you say it) (and a +1 if I have enough rep for that..). Thanks in advance!

Comment: A thing to note about using -novid: It will actually make your minimap in game display at a lower resolution than it should.  As far as I know, there is no fix for this at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @HighJumpKick for noting that. I did notice that, but I assumed it was happening to everyone. I guess we are going to have to wait for Valve to fix it :/ . Thanks again though!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to put a space between every launch parameter, otherwise it won't work.

Like this:

```
-console -novid -noaafonts -high -noforcemaccel -noforcemspd -useforcedmparms
```

The reason is, that the operating system only treats each parameter separately when separated by spaces. Then it puts the count of the parameters into a variable, known in Programming as argc, while the parameters reside in argv. So without a space, Dota 2 (respectively the Source Engine) would only receive 1 parameter at all and not recognize any of them, because they do not match any option.

Comment: Thank you! If worked! I can't +1 you because I would need 15 points of rep, but at-least can have a small one here : **+1**